# Show that finite dimensional topological subspaces are topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ using induction.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological Vector space and $Y$ a finite dimensional subspace with $\text{dim}Y = n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, one can show that every Isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $Y$ is a homeomorphism (i.e. continuous with continuous inverse), where we consider the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the subspace topology on Y. The vector space is over the field $\mathbb{C}$ and is per definition Hausdorff.

**Goal:** Prove this fact using induction over $n$.

**My progress so far:**

I was able to show the fact for $n = 1$. Now, let us suppose the fact holds for $n$, and consider an Isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to Y$. I was able to show that $\phi$ is continuous. However, I am struggling to show that $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

My idea was the following: Let $e_1,\dots,e_{n+1}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Since $\phi$ is an Isomorphism, $b_i = \phi(e_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ is a basis of $Y$. I can decompose Y into $Z:= \text{span}\{b_1,\dots,b_{n}\}$ and $V:= \text{span}\{b_{n+1}\}$. Now I consider the maps
$$
Y \to Z \times V; \; \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i b_i \mapsto (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i b_i,\lambda_{n+1} b_{n+1}) \\
\psi^{-1} \times \xi^{-1}: Z \times V \to \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C} \\
\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}; (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i e_i,\lambda_{n+1} e_{n+1}) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i e_i,
$$
where the second map is defined via $\psi(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i b_i$ and $\xi(\lambda) = \lambda b_{n+1}$
The second map is continuous iff $\psi:Z \to \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\xi: V \to \mathbb{C}$ are continuous. But here I can use the induction hypothesis and therefore conclude that the second map is continuous. The third map is also continuous. If the first map is continuous, I know that the composition of all three maps, which exactly equals $\phi^{-1}$, is continuous, which would conclude the prove.

**My problem:** I am not able to show that the first map is continuous. I know that it suffices to show that $\eta: Y \to Z; \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i b_i \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i b_i$ is continuous, but I am not sure how to do that.

**What I tried:** I tried to apply the standard definition of continuity in topological spaces, i.e. take $O \subset Y$ open and try to show that (since we consider the subspace topology on V) $\eta^{-1}(O \cap V)$ is open. However, I was not able to do it.

**Question:** How can I proceed to show that $\eta$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** My professor said that I should proof this fact only for normed spaces! Could someone verify my argument?

I consider a converging sequence in $Y$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda^k_i b_{i} = y_k \overset{k \to \infty}{\to} y = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda^k_i b_{i}.
$$
This implies
$$
0 = \lim_{k \to \infty} (y_k - y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lim_{k \to \infty} (\lambda^k_i - \lambda_i) b_{i}.
$$
Since $b_1,\dots,b_{n+1}$ are linearly independent, we must have $\lim_{k \to \infty} (\lambda^k_i - \lambda_i) = 0$ for each $i=1,\dots,n+1$.
Let $\xi: Y \to Z$ and $\zeta: Y \to V$ be the corresponding projections, then we have
$$
\|\xi(y_k) - \xi(y)\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i^k - \lambda_i| \|b_i\| \to 0, \\
\|\zeta(y_k) - \zeta(y)\| \leq |\lambda_{n+1}^k - \lambda_{n+1}| \|b_{n+1}\| \to 0,
$$
as $k \to \infty$, since $\lim_{k \to \infty} (\lambda^k_i - \lambda_i) = 0$ for each $i=1,\dots,n+1$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks!

Comment: See here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/#more-4889

Comment: You should explicitly mention that you consider complex TVS. Do require that a TVS is Hausdorff?

Comment: @ Paul Frost I am sorry, yes, I consider a complex TVS and the underlying Topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: @ PhoemueX Thanks. I think that this should work, but as mentioned under theorem 2 this would already imply that my finite dimensional subspace is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (And I guess similarly to $\mathbb{C}^n$), which would make the whole proof by induction redundant.

Comment: You seem to have swapped your original definition of $Z$ and $V$, as at the end you are treating $V$ as the span of $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post.

Comment: Do you know how to show that the map $p : Y \to V$, $\sum \lambda_i b_i \mapsto \lambda_{n+1} b_{n + 1}$ is continuous? Then the map $x \mapsto x - p(x)$ would also be continuous. A priori this is a map to $Y$, but lands in $Z$ by construction so is a continuous map $Y \to Z$ by properties of subspace topology.

Comment: I can restrict the argument to normend vector spaces. I edited the post. Can someone verify my proof? Should I also change the title?

Comment: Why do you want to use induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since $b_1,\dots,b_{n+1}$ are linearly independent, we must have $\lim_{k \to \infty} (\lambda^k_i - \lambda_i) = 0$ for each $i=1,\dots,n+1$.

That's a rephrasing of what you want to prove, and it's not obvious.

Here are some comments.

- Induction: I don't think it is the right way to go here. Try to do the first step explicitly, from $n=1$ to $n=2$; it is not clear to me how you would do that.
- The result you are trying to prove implies the result that all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent. So you cannot expect a totally elementary proof.
- One way to do your proof is to use the result that all norms are equivalent on $Y$. Then you can use the norm $$\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kb_k\Big\|=\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k|^2\Big)^{1/2}$$ and your isomorphism is automatically isometric.
- A second way is to recognize what the key step is when proving that all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional space. And that is to use the compactness of the unit ball in $\mathbb C^n$ (that is, Heine-Borel). You already know that $\phi$ is continuous. If $B\subset \mathbb C^n$ is the closed  unit ball, consider the restriction $\phi:B\to \phi(B)$. This is a continuous bijection. As continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, and every closed subset of $B$ is compact, $\phi$ maps  closed subsets of to closed sets. If $V\subset B$ is open, then $B\setminus V=B\cap V^c$ is closed, and so $\phi(B)\setminus \phi(V)=\phi(B\setminus V)$ is closed. Then $(\phi(B)\setminus \phi(V))^c=(Y\setminus B)\cup\phi(V)$ is open, and as these last two are disjoint, $\phi(V)$ is open. Thus $\phi$ maps bounded open sets to open sets. But an arbitrary open set $V\subset \mathbb C^n$ can be written as $V=\bigcup_m(V\cap B_m(0))$, and since $\phi$ is a bijection we get $\phi(V)=\bigcup_m\phi(V\cap B_m(0))$, a union of open sets. So $\phi$ maps open sets to open sets, and that's precisely the continuity of $\phi^{-1}$.